# Transit a day in Seoul (Indonesian citizen)

Tags: visas, transit, south-korea, indonesian-citizens

I'm an Indonesian citizen and traveling with family to Japan next month. My flight will transit in Seoul for a day.

Do I need visa for 1 day/night stop over ? How many hour max I can stay in Seoul during stop over ? Or should I apply visa ?

Answer (score 8):

> Yes, Indonesian citizens (ordinary passport) require a visa to enter Korea for stopover
>   for 1 day/night. Transit without of visa (twov) is possible for
>   Indonesian citizens provided they remain  in Seoul airport within 24
>   hours for next flight, however they will not be allowed to leave the
>   airport area. However there is still a possiblity to leave the transit area with **Transit Tourism** if approved br Korean Immigration

**Transit Tourism Program**: Holders of onward tickets transiting
Seoul Incheon (ICN), participating in the Transit Tourism
Program for a max.transit time of 72 hours leaving the transit area is permitted, provided staying in
Seoul, Incheon or Gyeonggi Province and leaving the tour group is
not permitted. Transit tour eligiblity is only possible after Korean Immigration approval, it is possible that any non-visa transit tour passenger(s) may not be allowed to enter Korea if any problem occurs in the course of the 
Korea's immigration inspection. Detail about Transit Tour reservation [Transit Tour reservation](https://www.airport.kr/pa/en/d/2/3/5/index.jsp)

> **Exemptions**:  Except for Passengers with a visa issued by Australia, Canada, New Zealand or USA to nationals of Indonesia can
>   avail visa free facility at Seoul (Korea)

Source : [Visa And Passport](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/visaform.htm)

[image]

> **Visa Free Enrty** : Diplomatic and official passport issued by indonesia can avail visa free entry to Korea for 30 days only.

Source : [Embassy Of Korea Singapore](http://sgp.mofa.go.kr/english/as/sgp/visa/issuance/)

[image]

Comment: What is the Transit Tourism Program, then?